# Algorithm to pick elements of collection to achieve average price

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

I need to solve the following problem:

I have an array of items with a price attached and I need to pick a given quantity to achieve a given weighted average price.

eg.

I can group quantities in bins for the same price for better understanding:

```
price    qty
$1.00    60
$1.04    80
$0.99    55
$1.10    130
```

Now I need to choose how many elements I need from each bin to achieve 100 elements at an average price = 1.035

Do you know an algorithm to search for an approximate solution without brute force combination? - I am time constrained too.

It looks some sort of the knapsack algorithm, although I'm not sure of the restrains I must use.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an integer linear programming problem.

Expressing this as a linear programming problem would mean having variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` with `a+b+c+d=100`, and `a*1+b*1.04+c*0.99+d*1.10=1.035*100` and `0<=a<=60`, `0<=b<=80`, `0<=c<=55` and `0<=d<=130`.

You don't explicitly say, but probably want integer solutions (that is, the quantities bought must be integers), hence it's an integer linear programming problem, rather than a linear programming problem. Although ILP problems are NP-hard in general, you can find solvers and algorithms online that will easily solve this small problem. For example, try GLPK.

Note also, that brute force will work well here; there's only 176851 combinations of `a,b,c,d` to try.

Comment: Nice answer. Are you sure there are around 4.5 million combinations? Since we know there must be 100 total elements, the maximum number of combinations (if each element were allowed to be repeated 100 times) would be nCr(4 + 100 - 1, 4) = 176851 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition). To be exact, I obtained 147616 total combinations of length 100 from the given multiset.

Comment: @JosephWood nCr(103, 4) is about 4.5 million. I think you made a calculation error.

Comment: My apologies, I wrote my first comment in haste. That should have been  nCr(4 + 100 - 1, 100) which is 176851. Remember, the second number in nCr is the size of the combinations, which means nCr(100 + 4 - 1, 4) would imply that we have 100 unique elements. Here we only have 4 unique elements.

Comment: @JosephWood you're right, edited. I was calculating the number of `a, b, c, d` that add up to 100 or less. nCr(103, 3) is correct (or equivalently nCr(103, 100) like you suggested).